# How to stop continuous pythos by bash using uohup

Tags: python, bash, pid, nohup, nvidia-smi

The title is ambiguous, so I add example.

I usually run python files by bash file.

Bash file name : `train.sh`

```
python train1.py 

python train2.py
```

Then I run `nohup bash train.sh > out.out &`.

So, `train1.py` and `train2.py` are run sequentially.
And when I found mistakes, I stopped using check PID using `nvidia-smi` and `kill -9 PID` .

However, of cousre, only `train1.py` stopped and then start `train2.py`.

#### What I want to do is.

I want stop both `train1.py` and `train2.py` even if current running file is `train1.py`.

In other words, I want stop running python file and files to be ran.

And I have one more question.

How can I get PIDs for running bash files?
(Assuming that 2 bash files like above example are running, I want to get PIDs for each.)

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

To get the PID of process (A program "python script" loaded into memory and executing is called Process)

```
ps -ef | awk '$8=="name_of_process" {print $2}'
```

To check that python a.py completed successfully as a required condition for running python b.py, you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python a.py && python b.py
```

To run both program background in same time

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
python a.py &
python b.py &
```